# Left outher join count rows from different table minus value different row

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello I have following SQL query

```
SELECT K.name AS Name, K.surname AS Surname, U1.akce AS Event, 
U2.[text] AS [Scheme], U1.[text]  AS [Registered under>], 
( U1.x - (
    SELECT Count(K.ubytov)
    FROM klient
    WHERE ubytov = U2.[text]) ) AS [Free space]
      FROM klient K
      INNER JOIN ubytov U1 ON U1.[text] = K.ubytov
      LEFT OUTER JOIN ubytov U2 ON U1.z = U2.id WHERE U1.akce = '140012-02'
    ORDER BY U1.[text]
```

I'm trying to achieve that in column `Free space` would be (value from ubytov.x that matches `U1.z = U2.id`) - (total number of rows from table klient that has the same value in U1.[text]=K.ubytov)

In table `klient` column `ubytov` I have values that matches ubytov.text and in ubytov.z I have value that matches ubytov.x in different row.

Would somebody help me solve this out please?

Thank you for your time.

An example:

Table klient

```
ID_K ubytov

1   RoomOwner 

2   RoomOwner
```

table ubytov

```
id text x z 

1 roomType1 2 NULL

2 RoomOwner NULL 1
```

Desired Output:

```
Name Surname Event Scheme Registered under: Free space

Nam1 Surname1 Even1 Scheme1 RoomOwnerName  0 // (because 2 counts from klient) - (roomType1 x)
```

Comment: Just an aside... I think people who create columns/tables with names that are reserved words, and thus require special delimiting *every* time you use them, should be sacked on the spot.

Comment: I think the desired output won't come as in `klient` table, you do not have `roomType1` value at all. Please review your question example and update.

Comment: @RavindraGullapalli Yes thats is the reason why I do `LEFT OUTER JOIN ubytov U2 ON U1.z = U2.id` to find that value in `roomType1`. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although, it wasn't much clear because of missing columns.
I tried to build the required query using a CTE expression. 
Here is the [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3c6a4/16) code.
Let me know, if this is what you are looking for.

```
   create table klient
   (
     id_k int,
     ubytov varchar(25)
   )
   go

   create table ubytov
   (
     id int,
     text varchar(25),
     x int null,
     z int null
   )
   go

   insert into klient(id_k, ubytov)
   select 1, 'RoomOwner'
   union select 2, 'RoomOwner'
   go

   insert into ubytov(id, text, x, z)
   select 1, 'roomType1', 2, null
   union select 2, 'RoomOwner', null, 1
   go       

   ;WITH cte_klint_counts_by_ubytov
   AS
   (
      SELECT
         ubytov,
         Count(ubytov) AS ubytovCount
       FROM klient
       GROUP BY ubytov
   )
   SELECT
     U2.[text] AS [Scheme],
     U1.[text] AS [Registered under>],
     (isnull(U1.x, 0) - isnull(c.ubytovCount, 0)) AS [Free space]
   FROM
     klient K
     INNER JOIN ubytov U1 ON U1.[text] = K.ubytov
     LEFT OUTER JOIN ubytov U2 ON U1.z = U2.id
     LEFT OUTER JOIN cte_klint_counts_by_ubytov c ON c.ubytov = U2.[text]
   ORDER BY u1.[text]
```